# How to refresh yajra datatables with compact information?

Tags: laravel

I have a blade with yajra table generated using the compact details passed to the blade. I want the yajra table to refresh the data whenever I do a ajax submit.

I tried to use `ajax.reload()` in my ajax post success but it gives off error "table id invalid json response" while `table.draw() / table.fndraw()` does not have any responses on the table.

how should I refresh the table data without page refresh?

Controller

```
public function request(Request $request)
{
        $lists = DB::table('requested')
                    ->select(
                        'name',
                        'email',
                        'id',
                    )
                    ->get();
        
        return view('request')->with(compact('lists'));
}
```

blade.php

```
<table id="requesttable">
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <a class="badge badge-info" id="elementPopover{{ $list->id }}" data-toggle="popover"
            onclick="$(`[data-toggle=popover]`).not('#elementPopover{{ $list->id }}').popover(`hide` )"
            title="Set Status"  data-content="<button onclick='$(`#elementPopover{{ $list->id }}`).popover(`hide` )' type='button' class='btn btn-secondary'>Cancel</button>"
            data-placement="right" data-html="true" targetOLD="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Action</a>
      </td>
```

Comment: try with `$('#requesttable').DataTable().ajax.reload();`

Comment: @Droid it alerts with "DataTables warning: table id=requesttable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1"